# How to give executable permission when running a binary from flask

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

I need to run a cpp binary from a flask based website. I am able to run the binary and retrieve the desired output with just python, but when I try to run the server and the cpp binary is called from flask, it says 'Permission denied.' How can I change the permissions of the binary so that it will run when called from my flask app? Alternatively, is there a better way to call this separate cpp binary that does not involve calling a shell script from python?

I have tried changing the permissions using chmod to make it executable, and so it works when I call the binary from a separate python script, but it does not work when the same script is run from the website.

Running this separately works:

```py
def function1(other):
    subprocess.call(shlex.split('./binary ' + other))
```

It does not work when I call the previous file, with error: 
Permission denied './binary'

```py
@app.route('/api/upload', methods = ['POST'])
def function2():
    function1("argument to binary")

    return "complete"
```

I expect calling function1 by myself to be the same as calling function1 within function2.

Comment: If you can run `./binary` manually this probably depends on the user running your Flask application. What are the full permissions of the file? (It might also depend on ACLs or other OS-level restrictions like SELinux, AppArmor, or similar tools on macOS and Windows.)

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x binary  <-- This is the full permissions of the file. I am running the Flask application locally right now, I am not sure how that changes permissions.

Comment: Okay, so it's not basic Unix permissions. What operating system are you on?

Comment: I am on Ubuntu. I edited my previous comment with more information.

Comment: Okay. (1) How _exactly_ are you running it? (2) Please try (temporarily) [disabling AppArmor](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor#Disable_AppArmor_framework) by running `sudo systemctl stop apparmor` and see if the problem persists. For now, this is just a diagnostic step; I don't recommend fully disabling it.

Comment: (1) I am running it essentially the same as
`app = Flask(__name__)
if __name__ == '__main__':
 app.run()` and running the file in my terminal using `python run.py`
(2) I tried the command and the problem persisted

Comment: Re: (1), sorry, I may not have explained properly. Are you running `python script.py` as your regular user? Or using something like `gunicorn` or `uwsgi`? Using another user? That kind of thing.

Comment: Are you 100% certain your path to `binary` is correct? Try using a full path.

Comment: I believe that the path is correct, and using a full path does not change the error. Giving an incorrect path resulted in an error that is not identical.

Comment: Does `subprocess.call(..., shell=True)` make a difference?

Comment: That kind of worked? To be specific, it no longer errors out, but it now displays `./binary: Permission denied
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Apr/2019 18:57:16] "POST /api/upload HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

Comment: Re: It did not work, it is still erroring, but it doesn't stop the whole application anymore when it denies permission.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what's going on. Good luck.